# Why does db.collection.find({}).maxTimeMS(100) return everything, but db.collection.find({}, {$maxTimeMS: 100}) only returns object IDs?

Tags: mongodb

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.8. According to the [$maxTimeMS reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/meta/maxTimeMS/), these two queries should behave identically:

```
> db.collection.find({}).maxTimeMS(100)
> db.collection.find({}, {$maxTimeMS: 100})
```

The first query does exactly what I want, but the second query restricts only returns the object IDs of the documents. I tried increasing $maxTimeMS to 100000000 and there was no change in behavior.

Why am I getting different results for these two commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a [bug in the documentation](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/DOCS-5125).

The reason that `db.collection.find({}, {$maxTimeMS: 100})` returns only the `_id` of each object is because mongoDB is interpreting the `{$maxTimeMS: 100}` portion of the query as a [projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations-introduction/#projections).

So it thinks you want to see all the documents and you want to see the fields `_id` and the field `$maxTimeMS`. Of course, none of your documents have a `$maxTimeMS` field, so they only show the `_id`.

The proper way to perform the query you want without the shortcut is:

```
db.collection.find({ $query: {}, $maxTimeMS: 100 })
```